# match float with comma and then replace comma with dot?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a text file which contains some different types of numbers: integers, binary and float. I want to match only float numbers and replace comma with dot.

example of my text file (there order is casual):

```
1000101 33434,34 1992 [3,41,4,5]
```

after conversion :

```
1000101 33434.34 1992 [3,41,4,5]
```

my code is :

```
lines = []
in_file = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in in_file:
    line = line.split(" ")
    for x in line:
        try:
            if isinstance(float(x.replace(',', '.')), float):
                line[line.index(x)] = float(x.replace(',', '.'))
        except:
            pass
    lines.append(line)
in_file.close()
```

but that will convert all other data to float, so what is the best way to resolve this?
I thought to use `regex` but I don't know how to do it in python.

Comment: well it won't work for another reason 3343,34 isn't a float anyway so that one will fail

Comment: What do you mean *"that will convert all other data to float"*? Strings are immutable, which is why you have to explicitly assign the conversion back into the `line` list. Have you tested this?

Comment: @gkusner well its a string , so I do replace comma with dot then i convert it to float

Comment: @gkusner but `float('3343,34'.replace(',', '.'))` is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know the reason why it convert all strings to float , what I want is another solution that will match string with float numbers and convert it to float

Comment: first after split check for list or tuple then try to do int conversion if all that fails its likely the one you want to convert

Comment: @gkusner after split I get a list like this `['100011','1231,3','232']`

Comment: Can there be things other than integers in the list? Can they be nested? How deep? Have you considered `ast.literal_eval`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah there are strings like `[3,41,4]` and I don't know what `ast.literal_eval` does

Comment: instead of replacing the string you could use local.atof() to convert them using a locale with commas as decimal point (e.g. de_DE.UTF-8)

Comment: @user2776193 ...then why not look it up?

Comment: @jtaylor what happen when i pass not float strings to `local.atof()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach, using regular expressions as well:

```
import re
with open('input.txt', 'r+') as f:
    newf = re.sub(r'(\s+[+-]?[0-9]+),([0-9]+\s+)',r'\1.\2', f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(newf)
```

test file:

```
1000101 33434,34 1992 [3,41,4,5] 
12,43 129012 91 [1,2]
1000101 33434,34 1992 [3, 41,4,5]
```

result:

```
1000101 33434.34 1992 [3,41,4,5] 
12.43 129012 91 [1,2]
1000101 33434.34 1992 [3, 41,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval

FLOAT_RE = re.compile('^\d+,\d+$')

lines = []
with open("input.txt", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip().split(" ")
        for x in line:
            i = line.index(x)
            if FLOAT_RE.match(x):
                x = x.replace(',', '.')
            line[i] = literal_eval(x)
        lines.append(line)

print lines
```

Comment: Fixed now. The `lines.append(line)` should be inside first for loop.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for you:

```
lines = []
in_file = open("input.txt", "r")
for line in in_file:
    line = line.split(" ")

    for x in line:
        tmp = eval(x)
        if isinstance(tmp, tuple):
            line[line.index(x)] = float(float(x.replace(',', '.')))
        else:
            line[line.index(x)] = tmp

    lines.append(line)
in_file.close()
```

it will convert everything to the right type

Comment: worked for me but there is a missing parentheses after  `float(float(x.replace(',', '.'))`

Comment: wait , it failed with this example `1111 28,09547 434 [94,2]` it said   `tmp = eval(x)
  File "<string>", line 1
    28,09547
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token`

Comment: it thinks 09547 is an octal - and 9 doesnt work for that - do a try except around eval and do the replace if it fails - that one is just funny

Answer (score 1):

if all your strings are in the same format you can sub only the first occurrence of `,`:

```
s = "1000101 33434,34 1992 [3,41,4,5]"

print re.sub(",",".",s,1)
1000101 33434.34 1992 [3,41,4,5]
```

Comment: thanks, it actually works so I don't know why it was downvoted, people are great when hiding behind a keyboard ;)